# Why is hibernate cascading by default when I don't have any CascadeTypes set

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, jpa-2.2

I'm running into the following exception when I'm trying to persist new `swipe` objects:
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.munch.database.models.bunch.Munch`

Here is the code I am executing:

```
databaseExecutor.executeAndRollbackOnFailure { entityManager ->
        munch.swipes.forEach {
            if (it.swipeIdKey.munchId != null) {
                entityManager.persist(it)
            } else if (it.updated) {
                entityManager.merge(it)
            }
        }
        entityManager.transaction.commit()
    }
```

I've also pasted my entities below for reference.
When `entityManager.persist(it)` is called, the above error is thrown. It is for some reason trying to persist the `OneToMany` side of the entity as well which will not work. I've made sure that the `CascadeTypes` arrays are empty for both so by my understanding only the `Swipe` that I call `entityManager.persist()` on should be written to the db.

If I replace `persist` with `merge` the operation succeeds but the merge causes hibernate to generate an additional `select` for the `Munch` and also a `select` for the `Swipe` which are unnecessary operations. The merge does not however seem to cascade the update operation to the `Munch` it only does the 2 select statements and 1 insert.

To recap:
Hibernate seems to be cascading the `Persist` operation when it shouldn't. A solution is to use `merge` instead but using `persist` should result only in `1 insert` where as `merge` results in `2 selects + 1 insert`

I'm out of ideas other than executing native queries to insert/update but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Here are my entities:

`Munch`

```
@Entity
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(
        name = "list-array",
        typeClass = ListArrayType::class
    )
)
data class Munch(
    @Column
    val name: String,
    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "munch",
    )
    val swipes: MutableList<Swipe> = mutableListOf(),
) {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    lateinit var munchId: String

    fun addSwipe(swipe: Swipe) {
        swipes.add(swipe)
        swipe.munch = this
    }
}
```

`Swipe`

```
@Entity
data class Swipe(
    @EmbeddedId
    val swipeIdKey: SwipeIdKey,
    @Column(nullable = true)
    val liked: Boolean,
) : Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "munchId")
    @MapsId("munchId")
    lateinit var munch: Munch

    @Transient
    var updated = false
```

`SwipeIdKey`

```
@Embeddable
class SwipeIdKey : Serializable {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    lateinit var restaurantId: String

    @Column(nullable = true)
    lateinit var userId: String

    @Column(nullable = true)
    var munchId: String? = null
}
```

Comment: After messing around with this the culprit seems to be this annotation `@MapsId("munchId")` for some reason having this specified forces Cascading when merging a `Swipe` or a `Munch`. I've removed that and the `munchId` field from the embeddedId and everything works as expected. Would love if someone could explain why

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are trying to persist and object that doesn't exist so you should use the CascadeType.PERSIST or persist the SwipeIdKey object first

Comment: SwipeIdKey is not an Entity so it is not persistable